# Should I build links to my images?

Tags: images, content, google-image-search, image-size

I know a basic of image seo is that we optimize image tag with "alt" and "title", but I noticed that my specific page get on top with some keywords but my images doesn't. Why?

How can I improve it?

- Improving onpage, add more h2, h3, internal link, add more content... etc ?
- Put link to images ? ----
- may be I create backlink to my images? --- keyword ?
- Should I create more attributes for my image like "width =", "height =",
- How about uploading new image to my host or use exist images on others site?

which is better?
does it affect to my images?
Thank so much

Comment: I am not sure why the down-votes. This is a perfectly valid question! It is possible that it was not fully understood. I, at least, will give you an up-vote for this useful question that is sure to help others in the future. I Thank You for asking such an important question and encourage others to up-vote the question if they agree.

Comment: Believe it or not I couldn't find a canonical question for this. This might end up being it. But I think it should be "cleaned up" a bit to better reflect the actual question at hand.

Comment: OP, it seems like you're asking a number of different questions in hopes that your SEO improves which may throw some people off.

Comment: Yes, I think I should set the title is "How to improve image seo ?"

Answer (score 2):

The first question you should know answer to is: is your image worth to rank? If yes, explain it to Google with following methods:

- Images should be better unique.
- They should have well descriptive alt and title
- Alt and title of image should correlate with url, title, h1 and topic of the textual content, where the image is in
- Image (and article) should better have descriptive structured data, specially for image like ImageObject etc.
- Images should contain descriptive EXIF data

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, images are hard for search engines to create search results for. There are some clues of course.

*Here is what can be done.*

1] The image alt text. The alt text should be a sentence with a subject, predicate, and object to allow better semantics analysis. Make the sentence as reasonably verbose as possible and not overly simple or too complex. The important thing to remember is that the alt text is to help users and describe the image. Make sure that you are not thinking in terms of keywords and rather about describing the image with simple language.

2] Images in content. Google and others use the content blocks around the image to understand the image. A content block is each paragraph and sets of paragraphs (taken as individuals and as a group) following a header tag. Header tags are important too. This means where an image exists, the *one* header tag above the image and the paragraph before and more importantly following an image are taken semantically to help understand the image. When the image alt tag and the semantic blocks agree semantically, these are taken as clues. For example, if you are talking about hunting dogs and describing popular bird dog breeds used in duck hunting, following a paragraph describing the pointer breed, an alt text like *Bo, an International 2014 Champion Pointer dog, is a popular bird dog breed for duck hunters in North America and in Europe.* would work semantically to indicate what the image is about and allow for a greater search capability. It not only indicates a pointer dog, but allows for searches such as *popular American duck hunting dogs*.

3] Keep in mind that capitalization is also a clue. Do not make your sentences all caps or capitalize terms that do not make sense, however, you should capitalize terms of importance that make sense. Do not try and game the system, but use this tactic appropriately like I have in the example.

4] If you do not mind direct links to your images, you can offer a link directly to the image. In this, the link text is also important and should also be a sentence with a subject, predicate, and object. It should follow the example I gave earlier in the alt text to enhance the understanding of the image and increase the search potential of the image.

5] One other option is the figure caption tag. While it is not clear how much effect this tag has on search, I would be willing to bet that Google pays attention to this tag. It would make sense. You can see how to use the tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp Again, use semantics to your full benefit.

6] URL/URI path. You can place the image in a directory that describes the image. In this, you will need to be brief such as */images/bird-dogs/popular/pointer/. Do not get carried away. This is one case where simple is best.

7] Image file name. You can name your image according to what it is. Again, you will need to be brief such as *pointers-are-a-popular-breed-bird-dog.jpg* Again, do not get carried away.

On-page clues listed in order of semantic importance: the page title tag, the link text, the image alt text, the content blocks, the one header tag above the image, URL/URI, file name.

Comment: @tunghk_54 Anytime! It is a really important question that appears not to have been asked here before. Congratulations!! Excellent question! It is rare that such a fundamental question is asked that has no existing answer. We are here for you. I am here everyday. I know SEO fairly well and how search engines work. So if you have any questions, please come back. This is a really friendly group here.

Comment: yes, I hope this question and your great answer will help some newbies like me, awesome. Thanks